# spring boot application to test with travis and deploy on Google Cloud

Tags: google-app-engine, spring-boot, travis-ci

Recently I ran my Spring Boot code into the Google Cloud platform. Now I want to introduce TRAVIS CI to my source code but I cant deploy it on Google Cloud because I receive the following error:

```
    Step #0: Pulling image: gcr.io/gcp-runtimes/java/runtime-builder@sha256:abe30c228acd8514d83430452b5a45eedea568b55d02d4ddaa2a374b1b086dd8
    Step #0: sha256:abe30c228acd8514d83430452b5a45eedea568b55d02d4ddaa2a374b1b086dd8: Pulling from gcp-runtimes/java/runtime-builder
    Step #0: Digest: sha256:abe30c228acd8514d83430452b5a45eedea568b55d02d4ddaa2a374b1b086dd8
    Step #0: Status: Downloaded newer image for gcr.io/gcp-runtimes/java/runtime-builder@sha256:abe30c228acd8514d83430452b5a45eedea568b55d02d4ddaa2a374b1b086dd8
    Step #0: Exception in thread "main" com.google.cloud.runtimes.builder.exception.ArtifactNotFoundException: No deployable artifacts were found. Unable to proceed.
    Step #0:    at com.google.cloud.runtimes.builder.buildsteps.PrebuiltRuntimeImageBuildStep.getArtifact(PrebuiltRuntimeImageBuildStep.java:77)
    Step #0:    at com.google.cloud.runtimes.builder.buildsteps.RuntimeImageBuildStep.run(RuntimeImageBuildStep.java:50)
    Step #0:    at com.google.cloud.runtimes.builder.BuildPipelineConfigurator.generateDockerResources(BuildPipelineConfigurator.java:104)
    Step #0:    at com.google.cloud.runtimes.builder.Application.main(Application.java:147)
```

I have configured files like:

- web.xml for using jetty
- appengine-web.xml for using the Google cloud
- .travis.yml for using Travis
- app.yaml for using Google cloud

Am I missing some files?

Comment: Just pointing out one thing. Based on your log, I believe you are deploying the App Engine flexible environment. The flexible environment doesn't use appengine-web.xml at all. appengine-web.xml is only relevant in the App Engine standard environment.

Comment: As it's been mentioned, it's not possible to use appengine-web.xml in the Flexible Environment. Make sure the relevant contents of your appengine-web.xml file and web.xml file is inserted in your app.yaml [1] file, and then delete both .xml files. As well as this, you should compile your project using Maven [2] before deploying.

[1]: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/java/upgrading#converting_from_appengine-webxml_to_appyaml

[2]: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/java/using-maven