# Google Cloud App engine after Travis building

Tags: google-app-engine, docker, spring-boot, google-cloud-platform, travis-ci

I wanted to host my spring boot application on the Google App engine after building on Travis.

I have configured the following in my .travis.yml but I'm always getting the following error from GCP:

```
Step #0: Exception in thread "main" com.google.cloud.runtimes.builder.exception.ArtifactNotFoundException: No deployable artifacts were found. Unable to proceed.
```

I dont know how to fix this problem in my code

```
sudo: false
language: java
jdk:
- oraclejdk8

cache:
  directories:
    - "$HOME/.m2/repository"

before_deploy:
  - mv target/healthcare-1.0.jar target/healthcare.jar

deploy:
  provider: gae
  skip_cleanup: true
  keyfile: secret.json
  project: healthcare-196408
  file: target/healthcare.jar
before_install:
- chmod +x mvnw
- openssl aes-256-cbc -K $encrypted_07ec618bb998_key -iv $encrypted_07ec618bb998_iv
-in secret.json.enc -out secret.json -d
```

My app.yaml file:

```
runtime: java
env: flex

handlers:
- url: /.*
script: this field is required, but ignored
```

**It seems like Travis isnt uploading my .Jar at all, but how can I fix this problem?**

I have tried to build it as docker with the same result:

```
Invalid or corrupt jarfile /app.jar --from docker
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [spring boot application to test with travis and deploy on Google Cloud](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49490727/spring-boot-application-to-test-with-travis-and-deploy-on-google-cloud)